# Test text in the corner of SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

Does anyone know how to get rid of the Test text in the top left corner of SharePoint?

[image]

Within the source code, it appears like this:

```
<div>test</div>
```

Comment: Are you have any custom web part ?

Comment: Nothing custom at all @JounMartin

Comment: Open a page in sharepoint designer , Search with 'test' then remove the test html tage from the page . save and bowse the page

Comment: Hi @SabithaS could you specify me the path of where i would be able to edit this in sharepoint designer please

Answer (score 0):

To hide it temporarily till find it is related you can also

- Open your portal with IE > Click F12 to open developer tool > try to select its ID.
- Add a Content Editor to your page then add the following CSS.

  `#ID  {style : display:none;}`

regarding tracking the issue ?

- open web part maintenance page and make sure that it's not related to any web part hosted on this page by adding ?contents=1 at the end of URL.
- If this link appears at all pages, open the master page via SharePoint Designer and search for the id that you already get from developer tools.
- try to hide it or check why you are using it.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I dont believe this has an ID, it is appearing as a plane div tag therefore i dont know where to get ride of it

Comment: Is it show in all pages  ? should you open master page with SP designer

Comment: Hello, i have got rid if the Test text but now ive got a banner appearing saying "The current page has been customized from its template. Revert to template. " How do i stop this from appearing? @jounmartin

Comment: don't revert to template , because it will' reset your master page to default template ,  tell me what's the latest step you are having do

Comment: I am editing the site pages using notepad, searching for the div tag and deleting it and then saving it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42661/discussion-between-joun-martin-and-jivvy).

Comment: I am available on chat awaiting your response

Answer (score 0):

Open your master page in SharePoint Designer -> Search for that DIV html (test) -> If found, Remove it -> Save and Check-In your master page